# Center image in a div with blank space around it using CSS

Tags: html, css

I currently have a background image that is taking up the whole div (due to background-size:contain). How can I make it only 75% or so of it's size (so there's white space all around it?). Screenshot is included below code.

I've tried using padding but unless I'm doing something wrong it doesn't seem to work.

```
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #0087F7;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('download.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

[image: screenshot of issue]

Comment: Give it a size using `background-size` or give us an example so we can help you out :)

Comment: @MarcHjorth I just tried this but when i set background-size to 75% it zooms in significantly so that the image is no longer contained within the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try putting `background-size` value in pixels.

```css
.dropzone-wrap {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px dashed #0087F7;
 }
.dropzone {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/essential-part-1/32/12-Download-512.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone-wrap">
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. Please let me know if any question.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's been bugging me for a while haha

Comment: It could be the best answer... but its not responsive. If you would want to make it responsive it would be wiser to put it into another container and just add padding.

Comment: @sonic, Thank you so much for the suggestion.  I have updated the code as per your comment.

Comment: yes, sort of and for example `height: 3vw` would show what I ment by responsive but I dont really know if this is what author of the question wants to achive. Maybe setting fixed `px` is enought .